# É possível converter um array [Any] para NSData?

Tags: ios, swift

Preciso gerar uma variável NSData a partir de um array que permite qualquer tipo de dado.

Tentei o seguinte cógigo, que não funcionou:

```
let a0 : Int8 = 3
let a1 : UInt16 = 231
let a2 : Int = 1024

let array : [Any] = [a2, a1, a0]
var data = NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count)
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte:

> array: [1024, 231, 3]
>
> data: <000400>

Quando eu tento converter um array de um tipo de dados apenas, a conversão ocorre sem problemas.

```
let arrayUInt8 : [UInt8] = [255, 0x02, 3]

let dataUInt8 = NSData(bytes: arrayUInt8, length: arrayUInt8.count)
```

Me retorna o seguinte:

> arrayUInt8: [255, 2, 3]
>
> dataUInt8: < ff0203>

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: @LeoDabus, na minha aplicação eu necessito dos campos com os tamanhos corretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce primeiro deveria extender IntegerType pra poder extrair os seus bytes em forma de NSData usando getBytes e usa sizeof() do dynamicType pra determinar a lenght do byte:

```
extension IntegerType {
    var data: NSData {
        var source = self
        return NSData(bytes: &source, length: sizeof(self.dynamicType))
    }
}
```

Com isso feito voce deve criar um método pra concatenar os seus dados antes de enviar:

```
func getDataToSend(first: Int8,_ second: UInt16,_ third: Int) -> NSData {
    let mutableData = NSMutableData()
    mutableData.appendData(first.data)
    mutableData.appendData(second.data)
    mutableData.appendData(third.data)
    return mutableData
}
```

E voce também pode extender NSData pra facilitar voce a extrair os seus elementos dela:

```
extension NSData {
    var getElements:(first: Int8, second: UInt16, third: Int) {
        var resultInt8: Int8 = 0
        var resultUInt16: UInt16 = 0
        var resultInt: Int = 0
        getBytes(&resultInt8, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: sizeof(Int8)))
        getBytes(&resultUInt16, range: NSRange(location: 1, length: sizeof(UInt16)))
        getBytes(&resultInt, range: NSRange(location: 3, length: sizeof(Int)))
        return (resultInt8, resultUInt16, resultInt)
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
let a0: Int8 = 3
let a1: UInt16 = 231
let a2: Int = 1024

let dataToSend = getDataToSend(a0, a1, a2)
print(dataToSend.length) // 11

let elementsFromData = dataToSend.getElements   // (.0 3, .1 231, .2 1024)
let firstElement = elementsFromData.first       // 3
let secondElement = elementsFromData.second     // 231
let thirdElement = elementsFromData.third       // 1024
```

Comment: Leo, arrumei novamente a minha resposta, faltava um detalhe, agora está compilando. Vc vê alguma diferença em utilizar uma ou outra resposta?

Comment: Voce pode fazer como voce achar melhor. Só acho que voce deveria usar sizeof() em vez de colocar a lenght manualmente

Comment: Ok, não sabia da utilização de extension. Obrigado pela atenção!!!

Comment: @Arubu extensions são a melhor maneira de voce arrumar o seu código e disponibilizar as funções em qualquer parte do seu app

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema utilizando NSMutableData desse jeito:

```
var a0 : Int8 = 3
var a1 : UInt16 = 231
var a2 : Int = 1024

let data = NSMutableData(bytes: &a0, length: 1)
    data.appendBytes(&a1, length: 2)
    data.appendBytes(&a2, length: 8)
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas funciona!!!
Se alguém tiver uma resposta melhor adicione aqui que eu troco a resposta aceita!!

Comment: Esse seu código nem compila aqui pra mim "Cannot convert value of type Int8 to expected argument type UnsafePointer<Void>

Comment: Se voce mudar a ordem dos elementos, como que voce vai saber aonde voce armazenou Int, UInt16 ou Int8 ?

Comment: Eu até posso te mostrar como voce deveria fazer isso mas eu não faço ideia como voce faria pra controlar o conteúdo da sua mutable data

Comment: @LeoDabus eu alterei o código, está compilando, testei no playground. Eu não vou mudar a ordem dos elementos, sempre vai ficar assim. Eu preciso montar os dados para enviar via bluetooth. Como eu disse, esse código funcionou para meu propósito, com certeza pode ter uma forma melhor de se fazer isso.

Comment: E outra coisa a lenght do Int é de 8 bytes (Int64) e não 4

Comment: está certo!!! esqueci de alterar a0 para variável, agora compila.

Comment: Compilar nao era o único problema voce tava fazendo o append só dos 4 primeiros bytes do Int e descartando os outros 4.

Comment: @LeoDabus Aproveitei e arrumei esse problema também.